# Plot a transformed distribution with an If function

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have a normal distribution $A \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ with a known cutoff point (percentile) on this distribution called $c$. Based on this point the distribution needs to be transformed which leads to a new distribution called $W$. Next, suppose $s$ equals a deterministic value.
The first part of $A \in [-\infty,c]$ becomes equal to a transformation of $A$ more specifically $\mathcal{N}(\mu+s,\sigma^{2})$, the second part $]c,+\infty]$ remains equal to $A$
To be clear, $c$ and $s$ are known in advance and do not need to be estimated.

To summarise:
$W = \begin{cases} A+s & \text{if } A \leq c \\ A & \text{if } A > c \end{cases}$

I used the following coded to obtain the mean and variance of $W$:

```
a = Exp[-(x - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)]/(Sqrt[2 Pi] σ);
domain[a] = {x, -Infinity, Infinity} && {Element[μ, Reals], σ > 0, Element[c, Reals], s > 0};
w = If[x <= c, x + s, x];
meand = Expect[w, a]
vard = Var[w, a]
```

Is there a quick way to plot the pdf of $W$ using *Mathematica* ?  (I also have *mathStatica*)

Comment: Have you tried defining your function with Piecewise and assigning some values to $s$, $\mu$, $\sigma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same approach as in @wolfies' answer (i.e., differentiating the `CDF` instead of using the `PDF`), gives the same result without the `DiracDelta`s:

```
tdist = TransformedDistribution[If[u <= c, u + s, u], 
        u \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ], Assumptions -> {Element[{c, s}, Reals]}]
 (* or Boole[u <= c] s + u instead of If[u <= c, u + s, u] *)

FullSimplify[CDF[tdist, w]]
```

[image]

```
pdF[ww_, cc_, ss_, μ0_, σ0_] := FullSimplify[D[CDF[tdist, w], w] /. 
                                 {μ -> μ0, σ -> σ0,  s -> ss, c -> cc}];

pdF[w, c, s, μ, σ]
```

[image]

If you add the assumption `s>0`, you get the same result as in @wolfies' answer:

```
pdF[ww_, cc_, ss_, μ0_, σ0_] := FullSimplify[D[CDF[tdist, w], w] /. 
        {μ -> μ0, σ -> σ0, s -> ss, c -> cc}, Assumptions -> {Element[c, Reals], s > 0}];
pdF[w, c, s, μ, σ]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[pdF[w, 2, 3, 2, 1.]], {w, -1, 7}, BaseStyle -> Thick, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a very nice question, and although it appears deceptively simple, it is not.

**The problem**

Let $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with pdf $f(x)$, and let $s>0$  and $c$ denote known constants. That is:

[image]

Find the pdf of $W$, where:

$$W = \begin{cases} X+s & \text{if } X \leq c \\ X & \text{if } X > c \end{cases}$$

The problem is not as simple as it looks, because the transformation from $X$ to $W$ is NOT one to one. In particular, there is a zone of overlap where both branches of the piecewise function can contribute to the same value of $W$.

**Solution**

The cdf of $W$ is simply $P(W<w)$:

[image]

where:

1. the `Prob` function is from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*, which the OP is using;
2. the `True` zone denotes $c<w<c+s$.

The pdf of $W$ is the derivative of the cdf wrt $w$:

[image]

with domain of support:

```
 domain[pdf] = {w, -Infinity, Infinity}  && {Element[c, Reals], s > 0};
```

All done.

**Plotting the pdf of $W$**

Given parameters, say:

```
params = {μ -> 2, σ -> 1, s -> 3, c -> 2};
```

... here is a plot of the pdf of $W$:

```
PlotDensity[pdf /. params, {w, -1, 7}]
```

[image]

**Monte Carlo check**

Here are some different parameters ($c$ has changed):

```
params = {μ -> 2, σ -> 1, s -> 3, c -> 2.8};
```

Here are $500,000$ pseudo-random drawings from $X$ and $W$:

```
xdata = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[2, 1], {500000}];
wdata = Map[If[# < 2.8, # + 3, #] &, xdata];
```

Now we can compare:

- the theoretical pdf (dashed RED curve) derived above
- to the empirical pdf (squiggly BLUE curve)

...

```
 FrequencyPlot[wdata, {0, 7, .02}, pdf /. params]
```

[image]

Looks fine. :)

**If you don't have mathStatica ...**

If you don't have *mathStatica*, one can still obtain the transformed pdf using just *Mathematica* with:

```
 mmasol = PDF[TransformedDistribution[Piecewise[{{x + s, x <= c}, {x, x > c}}], 
   Distributed[x, NormalDistribution[μ, σ]],  
   Assumptions -> {Element[c, Reals], s > 0}], w]
```

... but the solution produced is not very natural, and is expressed in terms of unnecessary `DiracDelta` functions, `UnitStep` functions and `Erf` functions:

```
(1/2)*DiracDelta[c + s - w]*(1 + Erf[(w - μ)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)] - 
    (Erf[(c - μ)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)] - Erf[(w - μ)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)] - 
         Erfc[(s - w + μ)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)])*(-1 +  UnitStep[c - w])) +(1/2)*DiracDelta[   c - w]*(-Erfc[(s - w + μ)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)] +   (-Erf[(c - μ)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)] +    Erf[(w - μ)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)] + 
         Erfc[(s - w + μ)/(Sqrt[2]*σ)])*(1 - 
   UnitStep[-c - s + w])) + (1/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*σ))*(UnitStep[c - w]/
 E^((s - w + μ)^2/(2*σ^2)) + 
    (E^(-((w - μ)^2/(2*σ^2))) + 
   E^(-((s - w + μ)^2/(2*σ^2))))*(1 - 
   UnitStep[c - w])*    (1 - UnitStep[-c - s + w]) + 
UnitStep[-c - s + w]/E^((w - μ)^2/(2*σ^2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Important Update!

This answer is **wrong**, for reasons that, even after @wolfies explanation, I had a hard time grasping! I'll leave it here as warning just as an example of not what to do! (It is mathematically unsound, to say the least)

```
A = Exp[-(x - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)]/(Sqrt[2 Pi] σ);
A1 = A /. (μ -> μ + s);
W = Piecewise[{{A1, x <= c}}, A];

Manipulate[
Plot[{W} /. {μ -> mu, σ -> sig, s -> ss, c -> cut}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {0, .5}}]
, {{mu, 1}, -10, 10}, {{sig, 2}, -10, 10}, {{ss, 2}, -10, 10}, {{cut, 1}, -10, 10}]
```

> [image]

Comment: How do you draw the vertical line joining the two pieces of `Piecewise`? Usually I just get a discontinuous plot. I'm studying your code but I don't see it.

Comment: That was a mistake, since there was supposed to be an exclusion there. You can force that behavior with `ExclusionsStyle -> Automatic`! `"PerformanceGoal"->"Speed"` also does it, but for the wrong reasons...